# Keeping all versions of a row, marking only one as current

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to SQL and trying to achieve something.

I have a table having fields like:

```
CustId   Fname   Lname    Address1    Address2  Zip    State  LoadDate   Flag
1        John     Leo      xxx        xxx       34532    VA    1/1/2012   Y
2        Mike     Saunder  xxx        xxx       94090    CA    1/1/2012   Y
```

Everytime I insert a new record it will set its flag to `Y` but lets say if any of the record value changes then new one will be set to Flag `Y` and old one to `N`. So for example if Mikes `address1` is changed.

```
CustId   Fname   Lname    Address1    Address2  Zip    State  LoadDate   Flag
1        John     Leo      xxx        xxx       34532    VA    1/1/2012   Y
2        Mike     Saunder  xxx        xxx       94090    CA    1/1/2012   N
3        Mike     Saunder  rrr        xxx       94090    CA    2/1/2012   Y
```

Comment: Shouldn't the two Mikes have the same `CustomerID`?

Comment: "I am new to SQL and trying to achieve something." So what are you trying to achieve and whats the problem?

Comment: @ypercube I was going to suggest the same thing in my answer but decided to keep it simple. It looks like this is his customer table, AND it's logging changes. I don't like it, but the solution I gave should work with his schema.

Comment: You seem to be implementing a row audit, there are well documented ways of doing this (including one here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603699/audit-each-inserted-row-in-a-trigger) so I would research those rather than implementing something new.

Comment: http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/

Comment: @IsaacFife: Yes but identifying a customer (whether by `CustId` or by `(Fname, Lname)` is needed to answer the question.

Comment: Hi All, thank you for your comments. Sorry for not making my question clear. i want to know how do i update this table for every changed record to the Flag set to N for old record and Y to new record? CustId is having a surrogate key.

Comment: One of the techniques I've used to track changes is to add a trigger to the table (Customers) and use the INSERTED and DELETED tables in the trigger to log the changes to another table (CustomersLog) that contains the original data, the operation performed, e.g. 'inserted', and the date/time of the change.  That way Customers only contains live data and I can always JOIN the live data to the log if I need to compare and contrast.  Queries against the live data aren't always filtering out the old rows, id's are stable, and I can move the logged data offline periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to say that the Fname/Lname pair is a unique key that lets you match rows:

```
declare @Folks as table ( CustId int, Fname varchar(10), Lname varchar(10),
  Address1 varchar(10), Address2 varchar(10),
  Zip varchar(9), State varchar(2), LoadDate date, Flag char(1) )
insert into @Folks ( CustId, Fname, Lname, Address1, Address2, Zip, State, LoadDate, Flag ) values
  ( 1, 'John', 'Leo', 'xxx', 'xxx', '34532', 'VA', '1/1/2012', '-' ),
  ( 2, 'Mike', 'Saunder', 'xxx', 'xxx', '94090', 'CA', '1/1/2012', '-' ),
  ( 3, 'Mike', 'Saunder', 'rrr', 'xxx', '94090', 'CA', '2/1/2012', '-' )

-- Before setting the Flag.
select * from @Folks

-- Computing a flying flag rather than using a stored value.
select *, case when LoadDate = ( select MAX(LoadDate) from @Folks as S where S.Fname = O.Fname and S.Lname = O.Lname ) then 'Y' else 'N' end as 'FlyingFlag'
  from @Folks as O

-- Updating all stored values.  Every bloody row.
update @Folks
  set Flag = case when LoadDate = ( select MAX(LoadDate) from @Folks as S where S.Fname = O.Fname and S.Lname = O.Lname ) then 'Y' else 'N' end
  from @Folks as O

-- Showing the result.
select * from @Folks
```

EDIT:
I still think this is not the direction you want to be heading.  For example, it doesn't gracefully accomodate more than one update per customer per day unless you rely on the CustId to be a tie breaker.

A marginally better solution would be to replace Flag with a PreviousId field that is NULL in the first row for a customer and in later rows contains the CustId of the row that is being superseded.  That links together the changes for each customer and provides a well defined order in the event that a customer is updated repeatedly on a single date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that custid is an identity column that auto increments.

```
update table set flag="N" where CustId= (insert Mike's current CustId here);
```

then

```
insert into table(Fname, Lname, Address1, Address2, Zip, State, LoadDate, Flag)
values(Mike, Saunder, rrr, xxx, 94090, CA, 2/1/2012, Y);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Isaac..question, if i have millions of records how do i update the table coz the query in your question would update for only Mike's record (correct me if i am wrong)